# Очередная ошибка header в php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.У меня появилась проблема с функцией header() в php скрипте.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at
http://.../a.php:13)
```

Перевод в кодировку UTF-8 не решило проблему.

Вот код:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['username']))
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if ($username == null) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Прошу дать совет или ссылку(google ничего не дал) на решение проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Думается мне - здесь всплывает notice который и становится причиной преждевременного вывода информации в браузер. Попробуй так:

```
$username = isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : null;
```

Comment: вы правы насчет notice сообщения, действительно оно выходит,но может ли это стать причиной ошибки?

Только что залил файлы на сервер,к своему глубокому удивления все работает как часы.Вполне возможно мой локальный open server некорректно отображает.Да,я попробовал ваш вариант,на сервере он тоже работает.
Будем искать неисправности.Огромное спасибо.

Comment: Если включена директива display_errors в сочетании с максимально строгим уровнем error_reporting - то причина стопудово в нотисе. Похоже, что на серваке настройки пыха другие.

Comment: Да так и есть стоит E_ALL.Будем менять настройки вывода ошибок.

Comment: Нет, не надо. Пускай остаётся. Нужно код писать так, чтобы не было ни единого нотиса. Как например в моем ответ-посте.

Comment: Приму во внимание и буду стараться без них.Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ну у вас уже вывод пошел до этого момента, как вы собрались заголовок взвести.
Поскольку в самом коде я таких действий не вижу (`session_start()` печатает заголовки, но *не завершает* их), предположу, что дело в самом исходнике.

Проверьте, нет ли у вас паразитных пробелов и переводов строк в начале/конце файла.

Comment: Лишних пробелов и переводов строк не обнаружил.И самое главное этот скрипт у меня работал час назад,а что сейчас с ним.Он же сам не мог сам модифицироваться.

Comment: Мистика :)

Comment: Возможно) но скорее всего сервер)

Comment: Значит, варнинги какие-то прут.

Answer (score 0):

На вопрос уже ответили, но хотелось бы добавить, что любой символ перед отправкой заголовков уже вызовет проблему. Лучше всего отключать некоторые отчёты об ошибках и оставлять только важные сообщения. Заголовки лучше всего стараться отправить в самом начале сценария.